# switch case in microsoft dynamics nav

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

HI I try to use a switch case in microsoft dynamics nav.

I have this:

```
CASE Betalingswijze OF
        'kontant':
           TemplateHeader.Code :='KNT-KLANT';

        'rekening':
           TemplateHeader.Code :='REK-KLANT';
        'automatische incasso':            
            TemplateHeader.Code  :='BIN-INC-KL';
        ELSE
        TemplateHeader.Code  :='KONTANT';
  END;
```

and this:

```
    RecRef.GETTABLE("<Customer>");
    //connect the payment method to the TemplateHeader and update the record:
    //rekening
    TemplateHeader.SETFILTER(TableID, FORMAT(18));
     IF Betalingswijze := 'kontant' THEN
    TemplateHeader.SETFILTER(TemplateHeader.Code,'REK-KLANT' );
    UpdateRecordTemplate.UpdateRecord(TemplateHeader, RecRef);

    //kontant
    TemplateHeader.SETFILTER(TableID, FORMAT(18));
    TemplateHeader.SETFILTER(TemplateHeader.Code,'KNT-KLANT' );
    UpdateRecordTemplate.UpdateRecord(TemplateHeader, RecRef);

//automatische incasso
TemplateHeader.SETFILTER(TableID, FORMAT(18));
TemplateHeader.SETRANGE(TemplateHeader.Code,'BIN-INC-KL' );
UpdateRecordTemplate.UpdateRecord(TemplateHeader, RecRef);
```

But now all the tree options are selected an not one.

So how to manage that only one selection will be selected?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have solved like this. I'v forgot to say that it is reading from a xml file.

```
CASE Betalingswijze OF
        'kontant':
           TemplateHeader.Code :='KNT-KLANT';
        'rekening':
           TemplateHeader.Code :='REK-KLANT';
        'automatische incasso':            
            TemplateHeader.Code  :='BIN-INC-KL';
        ELSE
        TemplateHeader.Code  :='KONTANT';
  END;
```

and in Company information, like this:

```
RecRef.GETTABLE("<Customer>");
//connect the payment method to the TemplateHeader and update the record:
//rekening
TemplateHeader.SETFILTER(TableID, FORMAT(18));
 IF TemplateHeader.Code = 'KNT-KLANT' THEN
TemplateHeader.SETFILTER(TemplateHeader.Code,'REK-KLANT');

//kontant
  IF TemplateHeader.Code = 'REK-KLANT' THEN
TemplateHeader.SETFILTER(TemplateHeader.Code,'KNT-KLANT' );

//automatische incasso
  IF TemplateHeader.Code  = 'BIN-INC-KL' THEN
TemplateHeader.SETFILTER(TemplateHeader.Code,'BIN-INC-KL' );
UpdateRecordTemplate.UpdateRecord(TemplateHeader, RecRef);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the right code:

```
RecRef.GETTABLE("<Customer>");
TemplateHeader.RESET;
TemplateHeader.SETFILTER(TableID, FORMAT(18));
CASE Betalingswijze OF
  'kontant'  : TemplateHeader.setrange(Code,'KNT-KLANT');
  'rekening' : TemplateHeader.setrange(Code,'REK-KLANT');
  'automatische incasso': TemplateHeader.setrange(Code,'BIN-INC-KL');
  ELSE TemplateHeader.setrange(Code,'KONTANT');
END;  
IF TemplateHeader.FINDFIRST THEN
    UpdateRecordTemplate.UpdateRecord(TemplateHeader, RecRef);
```

You've made a few mistakes in your code:

- setting the code in your first CASE is not doing anything with your SETRANGE or SETFILTER
- you need to actually get the record using FINDFIRST/FINDSET - use the appropriate one
- always use RESET before setting filters

I hope it helps.

Cheers

Comment: At azatoth. Thank you for your answare. I have solved.

Comment: @SavantTheIncredible Hi, please mark as answer then. Always happy to help!